# Check based on columns condition in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

How to solve this issue in SQL Server

```
Table: emp 

Pid  | Address           |  City | datetime                   |  Edate       | level
1    | Homeless          |  Chen | 2014-11-13  09:32:14.000   |2013-02-10    |3
1    | 3913 W. Strong    |  Chen | 2011-03-044 19:04:10.000   |2014-02-04    |7
1    | 1100 W MALLON     |  Chen | 2014-11-13  09:32:14.000   |2013-02-10    |5
2    | 610 W GARLAND #3  |  Hyd  | 2013-11-13  09:32:14.000   |2014-04-02    |4
3    | banvanu           |  chen | 2015-03-044 06:04:10.000   |2015-05-06    |6
3    | naneku            |  chen | 2015-03-044 06:04:10.000   |2015-06-09    |4
```

based on above table I want output like below

```
Pid  | Address           |  City | datetime                   |  Edate       | level
1    | 1100 W MALLON     |  Chen | 2014-11-13  09:32:14.000   |2013-02-10    |5
2    | 610 W GARLAND #3  |  Hyd  | 2013-11-13  09:32:14.000   |2014-04-02    |4
3    | naneku            |  chen | 2015-03-044 06:04:10.000   |2015-06-09    |4
```

we need to  get address,city from same table based on below conditions

We have few condition to get output : first level  check the max(datetime) based on pid if max(datetime) values same for same pid then same pid need to check max(edate) if we get again same value then we need to check max(level) particilar patient  the retrieve address,city for that pid

I tried like below

```
select * from (select *,row_number()over(partition by id ,order by datetime,edate,level)as rno
               from emp)
where rno=1
```

but above query not given expect result
please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server

Comment: If you want the maximum datetime, and maximum edate, and maximum level, should it not be sorting in descending order --  `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY datetime DESC, eDate DESC, level DESC)`

Comment: When you add tags to a question, please don't use tags for every version. Just use the generic sql-server and if applicable the tag for the specific version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use descending order in the window function:

```
select [Pid], [Address], [City], [datetime], [Edate], [level]
from (
  select *
       , rn= row_number() over (partition by [pid] 
                                order by [datetime] desc, 
                                         [edate]    desc, 
                                         [level]    desc
                               )
  from emp
) a
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: @srinivasa If this solved your problem then you should consider [accepting it as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179361)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH Empgroup AS (
    SELECT
        Pid
        , [Address]
        , City
        , [DateTime]
        , EDate
        , [Level]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Pid ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC, EDate DESC, [Level] DESC) AS RN
    FROM
        Emp
)
SELECT
    Pid
    , [Address]
    , City
    , [DateTime]
    , EDate
    , [Level]
FROM
    Empgroup
WHERE
    RN = 1
```

The functional difference is in the ordering of the `ROW_NUMBER()`. I also elected to use a Common Table Expression to make the query clearer, however.

Comment: In what way do you think using a common table expression make the query more efficient? I appreciate that subjectively, a common table expression may be easier to read, but it would have absolutely no impact on performance, it is purely an aesthetic change.